Inconsistent KeyboardAvoidingView Behavior on Different iPhone Models
Why does KeyboardAvoidingView position itself at different heights with more margin on various devices? On my iPhone XS and 15 Pro Max, it isn't right up against the keyboard as it should be. How can I ensure it stays attached to the keyboard correctly across different iPhone models?
Image 1
Image 2
I used KeyboardAvoidingView in my React Native application to ensure the input field stays above the keyboard. I expected it to consistently position itself right against the keyboard edge on all devices.
